# converting similar click event actions into a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have 4 click events that use nearly the same tracking code so I am thinking that this code would be better residing in a function, what I would like to know though is how do I set certain values that are different from event to event? Do I need to pass parameters into the new function that take on the value?

My click event code is:

```
$('a.close', '#contents').on('click', function(){
    s=s_gi('myapp');
    s.linkTrackVars="None"; 
    s.linkTrackEvents="None";
    s.tl(this,'o','myapp_fb:new_story:a');
});

$('a.next', '#contents').on('click', function(){
    s=s_gi('myapp');
    s.linkTrackVars="None"; 
    s.linkTrackEvents="None";
    s.tl(this,'o','myapp_fb:new_story:b');
});

$('a.prev', '#contents').on('click', function(){
    s=s_gi('myapp');
    s.linkTrackVars="None"; 
    s.linkTrackEvents="None";
    s.tl(this,'o','myapp_fb:new_story:c');
}):

$('a.share', '#contents').on('click', function(){
    s=s_gi('myapp');
    s.linkTrackVars="None"; 
    s.linkTrackEvents="None";
    s.tl(this,'o','myapp_fb:new_story:d');
});
```

Comment: Where's `s` coming from?

Comment: s is coming from a separate js file supplied by omniture

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like that:

```
var clickHandler = function(value) {
    s=s_gi('myapp');
    s.linkTrackVars="None"; 
    s.linkTrackEvents="None";
    s.tl(this,'o',value);
}

$('a.close', '#contents').on('click', function(){
    clickHandler('myapp_fb:new_story:a');
});
```

Comment: I was going to go the jQuery plugin route, but that's a perfectly reasonable refactor.